# Append every 5 Seconds

Tags: python, list, timer, append

I want to append the letter X to a list every 5 Seconds. My code so far:

```
import threading

def Seconds():
     threading.Timer(5.0, Seconds).start()
     List = []     
     n = "X"
     List.append(n)
     print List
Seconds()
```

I want to have ONE list which grows every 5 Seconds and is saved into a txt. file every 5 Seconds. The purpose of this code is checking the running time of my battery powered system. The code starts together with the system. When the battery goes flat i would like to read out the text file to see how long the code was executed and therefore how long my system managed to run on batteries.

Comment: Why not to use Queue? they are thread-safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run a stand alone process.

```
def alive():
    with open("log.txt", "w") as output:
        while True:
            time.sleep(5)
            output.write("X")
            output.flush() # important to ensure that long periods 
                       # of 'X' are not kept in buffer and lost on power down. 

p = Process(target=f, args=('bob',))
p.start()

time.sleep(40) # simulate real program
p.terminate() # eventually
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your embedded/battery powered system using Unix? This could be easier achieved with a bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    cat /proc/uptime > log.txt
    sleep 5
done
```

You then get the exact uptime. Note though in measuring this data you could be inadvertently using more energy by not allowing the processor to go into a lower power usage state and causing additional disk writes to occur.

Edit, a rough Python version not dependant on OS

```
#!/bin/python
import time

starttime = time.time()

while True:
    with open('log.txt', 'w') as log:
        print >> log, time.time() - starttime
    time.sleep(5)
```

Note the time will be off by the amount of time it takes before this script is run.

Comment: The OP's use case was gather the run time of a system, this fits bill. No need to use a sledgehammer to hit a nail.

Comment: Probably you are right. But there is no information about OS in the question (whether it's **nix** or not).